# Postgres Regex match the first 11 char unless there is a space or dash

Tags: regex, postgresql

```
12345678-1
12345678 1356456456456
221345243545634563546
```

using the above strings, i am trying to match the first 11 characters unless thee is a dash or a space, then grab everything (only first 8) up until the space/ dash...

i have tried `\^(.*?)-\` which grabs the first 8 of the first string only (as expected. or `\^(.*?) \`which rightfully grabs the first 8 of the second string. But `\^(.*?)(-| )\` doesn't work. Nor does `([0-9]{8,11}) as this just skips over the space and includes the extra bits...

How can I only pull the first 11 numbers unless there is a dash or space, then pull everything up to the dash/ space (fixed 8 chars)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an anchor to start:

```
^[0-9]{8,11}
```